# lane lines keeping project using opencv-python(Raspberrypi) and Arduino

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, raspberry-pi, hough-transform

I have an air drone with four motors and wanted to make it fly between two straight lines.

- The first problem:

its initial position will be in the middle at certain height but because of the air factors it may deviate (up or down) or (left or right). I have calculated the error when it deviates left or right using the camera, but still don't know how to calculate the error of the height (using the camera too without pressure sensor).

- The second problem:

after calculating these errors how to convert them from an integer to a real move.

Sorry, I couldn't provide my code. it is too large and complicated.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using a single camera to calculate distance is not enough.

However, if you're using a stereo camera, you can get a distance data pretty easily. If you want to avoid using a pressure sensor, you may want to consider using a distance sensor(LIDAR or ultrasonic: check the maximum range on these) to measure the height at which your drone will fly. In addition to this, you'll require a error control algorithm eg. PID algorithm to make your drone fly at a constant height.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UR0hOmjaHp0) is a fantastic source for understanding the fundamentals of PID.

2)For implementation:
In my opinion, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JFTJ2SS4xyA) video is awesome for understanding how your sensor data will get converted to an actual movement and will help you can create an analogy. You'll also get a headstart on the code provided.